# Find the subset of a set of integers that has the maximum product

Tags: python, algorithm

Let A be a non-empty set of integers. Write a function **find** that outputs a non-empty subset of A that has the maximum product. For example, **find([-1, -2, -3, 0, 2]) = 12 = (-2)*(-3)*2**

Here's what I think: divide the list into a list of positive integers and a list of negative integers:

1. If we have an even number of negative integers, multiply everything in both list and we have the answer.
2. If we have an odd number of negative integers, find the largest and remove it from the list. Then multiply everything in both lists.
3. If the list has only one element, return this element.

Here's my code in Python:

```
def find(xs):
    neg_int = []
    pos_int = []
    if len(xs) == 1:
        return str(xs[0])
    for i in xs:
        if i < 0:
            neg_int.append(i)
        elif i > 0:
            pos_int.append(i)
    if len(neg_int) == 1 and len(pos_int) == 0 and 0 in xs:
        return str(0)
    if len(neg_int) == len(pos_int) == 0:
        return str(0)
    max = 1
    if len(pos_int) > 0:
        for x in pos_int:
            max=x*max
    if len(neg_int) % 2 == 1:
        max_neg = neg_int[0]
        for j in neg_int:
            if j > max_neg:
                max_neg = j
        neg_int.remove(max_neg)
    for k in neg_int:
        max = k*max
    return str(max)
```

Am I missing anything? P.S. This is a problem from Google's foobar challenge, I am apparently missing one case but I don't know which.

Now here's actual problem:
[image]

Comment: I meant the numerically largest negative, as -1 > -3

Comment: Do max_neg = abs(neg_int[0]).. and do comparisons based on absolute value

Comment: Does the set need to be a minimally sized set?  e.g. `[2, 3, 1, 1]` results in the same product as `[2, 3]`.  Does the challenge say anything about how you should resolve this discrepancy?

Comment: No it doesn't. I should say technically it isn't a set since repeated values can exist.

Comment: @Lewis: think I found the error with your code:
Say the input is: `[-1]`, your code returns `0` as the answer.. Also in some edge cases you `return 0` instead of `return str(0)`

Comment: @User_Targaryen: It actually prints -1 since I specified that if the list has only one element then we will return the element. if len(xs) == 1:
    return str(xs[0])

Comment: @Lewis: in some edge cases you return 0 instead of return str(0).. Change it

Comment: @User_Targaryen: I updated my code but it still doesn't work. I guess it doesn't matter for small integers.

Comment: **Hint:** Calculate the solution in one loop. Your reasoning is good, but your code looks overcomplex. Fewer special cases, fewer bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution that doesn't require libraries :

```
def find(l):
    if len(l) <= 2 and 0 in l: # This is the missing case, try [-3,0], it should return 0
        return max(l)
    l = [e for e in l if e != 0] # remove 0s    
    r = 1
    for e in l: # multiply all
        r *= e 
    if r < 0: # if the result is negative, remove biggest negative number and retry
        l.remove(max([e for e in l if e < 0]))
        r = find(l)
    return r

print(find([-1, -2, -3, 0, 2])) # 12
print(find([-3, 0])) # 0
```

**EDIT :**

I think I've found the missing case which is when there are only two elements in the list, and the highest is 0.

Comment: That's a very nice solution. But it's failing the same test case as my code. (Sadly I have no idea which case it is)

Comment: @Lewis my thought too, but really I can't see what case it is neither. I'll keep looking, this problem is fun :)

Comment: Actually your solution fails another case too: find([0,-1)] prints 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @Lewis oh I just edited my solution, I thought this was the missing case.

Comment: Do they give any information at all about it? Are you sure they test lists of integers? for instance [0.5, 0.5] will return 0.25 when 0.5 is higher

Comment: I just updated the question. Please see the pic in the description. : )

Comment: When you give this code a single negative number, `find([-3])` it returns `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this problem with `reduce` (in `functools` in Py3)

```
import functools as ft
from operator import mul

def find(ns):
    if len(ns) == 1 or len(ns) == 2 and 0 in ns:
        return str(max(ns))
    pos = filter(lambda x: x > 0, ns)
    negs = sorted(filter(lambda x: x < 0, ns))
    return str(ft.reduce(mul, negs[:-1 if len(negs)%2 else None], 1) * ft.reduce(mul, pos, 1))

>>> find([-1, -2, -3, 0, 2])
'12'
>>> find([-3, 0])
'0'
>>> find([-1])
'-1'
>>> find([])
'1'
```

Comment: This solution seems to blow up on input [-1] and doesn't return strings.

Comment: Ok, it didn't cover all the special cases. Added a single guard.

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def find(array):
    negative = []
    positive = []
    zero = None
    removed = None

    def string_product(iterable):
        return str(reduce(mul, iterable, 1))

    for number in array:
        if number < 0:
            negative.append(number)
        elif number > 0:
            positive.append(number)
        else:
            zero = str(number)

    if negative:
        if len(negative) % 2 == 0:
            return string_product(negative + positive)

        removed = max(negative)

        negative.remove(removed)

        if negative:
            return string_product(negative + positive)

    if positive:
        return string_product(positive)

    return zero or str(removed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in one loop:

```
def max_product(A):
    """Calculate maximal product of elements of A"""
    product = 1
    greatest_negative = float("-inf") # greatest negative multiplicand so far

    for x in A:
        product = max(product, product*x, key=abs)
        if x <= -1:
            greatest_negative = max(x, greatest_negative)

    return max(product, product // greatest_negative)

assert max_product([2,3]) == 6
assert max_product([-2,-3]) == 6
assert max_product([-1, -2, -3, 0, 2]) == 12
assert max_product([]) == 1
assert max_product([-5]) == 1
```

Extra credit: what if the integer constraint were relaxed? What extra information do you need to collect during the loop?